# Copy latest timestamp from one table to another

Tags: mysql

I am trying to copy the latest timestamp from rows in one table to another table, by matching a contact ID.  Basically I have a table of call records, and I want to add a column to my contacts table that will contain the timestamp of the most recent call to that contact.  The relevant columns are:

contact.leadId => callrecord.cid, contact.lastcall => callrecord.time

This is a one-to-many relationship, as there is only one row for each contact but the callrecord table will have possibly many rows for that contact.

I have tried this:

```
UPDATE contact 
JOIN callrecord ON contact.leadId = callrecord.cid 
SET contact.lastcall = MAX(callrecord.time) 
WHERE 1
```

But I get an error saying "Invalid use of group function".

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the aggregation first:

```
UPDATE contact c JOIN
       (select cid, MAX(cr.time) as maxtime
        from callrecord
        group by cid
       ) cr
       ON c.leadId = cr.cid 
  SET c.lastcall = MAX(cr.time) ;
```

With an index on `callrecord(cid, time)`, the following should perform better:

```
UPDATE contact c
    SET c.lastcall = (SELECT MAX(time) FROM callrecord cr WHERE c.leadId = cr.cid);
```

To maintain this, though, you should have an `insert` trigger on `callrecord` (and perhaps `update` and `delete` triggers as well).